# Can I mirror wordpress public REST API to my self hosted wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, jetpack, self-hosting

I have a self hosted wordpress site, for example, www.example.com, 
I can access the site's posts and other data through wordpress official **REST API** site "https://public-api.wordpress.com" via **Jetpack** plugin installed and enabled.

But I can not access "https://public-api.wordpress.com" this site in my country since it is **blocked** by firewall that deployed within my country.

So,my question is:
Can I **mirror** this feature to my self hosted wordpress site so that I can directly access contents in my local **APP**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used the official api, but i have used these plugins to create api for my wordpress. https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/ and https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/.

The plugins are preety functional, you just need to install them and start using the REST API. There might not be too many features in them but they get the job done. for advance stuff you will have to modify the plugin to your needs.

Comment: OK,thank you,I am studying json-rest-api this plugin now.I am reading docs to create local apps